# Jenkinsfile bind exposed ports from one container to localhost on another linked container

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-docker

I have a service that exposes certain ports. I want the container of this service linked to a Jenkins slave container and have the same ports available on localhost of the Jenkins slave container.

```groovy
docker.image('some-service').withRun() { l ->
  docker.image('jenkins-slave').inside("--link ${l.id}:my-service") {
    echo "Exposed ports from some-service are available on localhost on jenkins-slave"
  }
}
```

How do I do this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Linking containers doesn't publish ports on localhost, but instead connects the private networks between the two containers. Using your above example, the exposed ports (`EXPOSE` syntax in Dockerfile) on `some-service` would be available to `jenkins-slave` container using hostnames for discovery:

```
$ nc my-service 8080
```

Docker will also inject a whole bunch of environment variables. To see this without Jenkins in the mix, just run a couple of containers by hand.

First run the service container as a daemon:

```
$ docker run --rm -d --name some-service tutum/hello-world
d26f4f768218006060e5bed6f228a979be51246722f70e2bc75db73b9d21fd62
```

Then run an Alpine container:

```
$ docker run --link some-service:my-service -it alpine:3.7 sh
```

Checkout the environment:

```
/ # env
MY_SERVICE_PORT_80_TCP=tcp://172.17.0.6:80
HOSTNAME=b1a44bdfa022
SHLVL=1
HOME=/root
TERM=xterm
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
MY_SERVICE_PORT=tcp://172.17.0.6:80
MY_SERVICE_NAME=/vigilant_beaver/my-service
MY_SERVICE_PORT_80_TCP_ADDR=172.17.0.6
PWD=/
MY_SERVICE_PORT_80_TCP_PORT=80
MY_SERVICE_PORT_80_TCP_PROTO=tcp
```

Connect to the dependent service:

```
/ # wget -q -O- http://my-service/
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello world!</title>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <style>
    body {
        background-color: white;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 50px;
        font-family: "Open Sans","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    }

    #logo {
        margin-bottom: 40px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <img id="logo" src="logo.png" />
    <h1>Hello world!</h1>
    <h3>My hostname is d26f4f768218</h3>    </body>
</html>
```

If your networking needs get more complicated, consider setting up a [Docker network](https://docs.docker.com/network/), instead.

Cheers!